# How to format this string in java?

Tags: java, string

How can a String be formatted in Java?

My String contains only numbers like "1234.0" and I want to return the formatted number.

For example, given the string "1234.0" the result should be the String "1234".

Comment: you only  want to erase decimal positions? no rounding needed? what have you tried?

Comment: `String formatted = String.format(format, args...)` will help you

Comment: "Lazy Coder" , indeed.

Comment: One approach, commonly used by programmers, is... writing code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html or just remove every character after the comma (Substring from the start of the string to the comma).

Comment: @JordiCastilla ...yes i want to erase decimal positions..I am trying to use String.Format("...", arg);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
   String formatted = String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble("12345.0"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   // input is not a number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions as well:

```
String n = "1234.0";
n.replaceAll("\\.0*$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat like this:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("####");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
```

You can find more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)